# How to update the Python interpreter call for terminal

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-arguments, python-3.10

I have wrote a program using the new 3.10 syntax, specifically, `match` `case` statements. Now I need to run the program using terminal.

`python3 main.py` gives back this error

```
    match str(i):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
I suppose the interpreter my terminal uses is of old version (<3.10), but I have no idea how to update it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Type `which python3` or just `python3` and check what is launched.
You can change the "default" version by `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1` and after update check with `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

Comment: This depends heavily on what package manager you are using, or whether you want to bypass any package manager and install from source.